# PHP Echo - why am i getting ghost tags in my HTML?

Tags: html, tags, echo

This is in the PHP as part of an `ECHO <<< END ... END;` statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ismaxlength(obj){
var mlength=obj.getAttribute? parseInt(obj.getAttribute("maxlength")) : ""
if (obj.getAttribute && obj.value.length>mlength)
obj.value=obj.value.substring(0,mlength)
}
</script>
<BR><BR>
Mark1
<BR><BR>Mark2
<table style="width:1000px; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" border="4" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td >

        <form action="add.php" method="post">
        Message
```

This is the output HTML (just posting a section of what's generated from above:

```
Mark1
<br><br>Mark2
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><table style="width: 1000px; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" border="4" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
      <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <form action="add.php" method="post">
            Message<br>
```

Why is that happening? (the `<BR><BR><BR><BR>` over and over)

i'm editing with Windows Note Pad (win7) , word wrap off, and i even deleted the entire section and re-typed it from scratch because i couldn't find the cause of some random tag closings (such as `')

Any suggestions of what could be causing this?

Comment: HTML and CSS, by it self will not generate any new html content (such as "<br>") so the only thing(s) that can cause this is client/server side scripts (javascript or php most likely in your case)

Comment: After your reminder that HTML and CSS will not generate any new HTML comments i went through my code again. I found that there were some <BR> placed outside of some table <TR> tags. ("</TR><BR><TR>") Removing these solved the problems. apparently, because firefox did not know what cell to place these in, it instead parsed them as being prior-to-table content.  Thanks for helping me to catch a lazy braincell with your reminder.

Comment: Np, and you gotta love firefox assumptions, haha